# Sizing image to Fill Divs Based on Orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what I am trying to do is have images fill a div whilst maintaining their aspect ratio. So I am using jquery to identify whether they are portrait or landscape, and set either width or height from there.

My problem is the code gives all the images landscape class. I am at my wits end to know why...

Thank you!

HTML

```
    <div class="prop">
    <div class="propimage"><img src="{@image}" alt="{@prop_name}"></div>
    <div class="propname">{@prop_name}</div>
    <div class="propdescription">{@description}</div>
    <div class="propprice">{@price}</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .portrait img {
    width: 100%;
    }
   .landscape img {
    height: 100%;
    }
   .propimage img {
        display: block;
    }
    img {
        max-width: none;
    }
    .propimage {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
    }
```

SCRIPT

```
    <script>
    $(".propimage").each(function(){
        // Uncomment the following if you need to make this dynamic
        //var refH = $(this).height();
        //var refW = $(this).width();
        //var refRatio = refW/refH;

        // Hard coded value...
        var refRatio = 240/300;

        var imgH = $(this).children("img").height();
        var imgW = $(this).children("img").width();

        if ((imgW/imgH) < refRatio){ 
            $(".propimage").addClass("portrait");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("landscape");
        }
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: What determines when images should be landscape, and when should they be portrait?

Comment: The native size of the image (I think!)

Answer (score 0):

Please upload You code on js fiddle or paste the link so we can see working example of your code.  Meanwhile just try this code

```
<script>
    $(".propimage").each(function(){
        // Uncomment the following if you need to make this dynamic
        //var refH = $(this).height();
        //var refW = $(this).width();
        //var refRatio = refW/refH;

        // Hard coded value...
        var refRatio = 240/300;

        var imgH = $(this).children("img").height();
        var imgW = $(this).children("img").width();

        if (imgW=<200 || imgH<=300)){ 
            $(this).children("img").css("width","100%");
            $(this).css("width","100%");
        } else {
             $(this).children("img").css("height","100%");
             $(this).css("height","100%");
        }
    })
    </script>
```